# Is Gltf2 Animation supported in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I've got a Gltf2 model which contains an animation (I checked on sandbox.babylonjs.com and I see the animation, so the gltf is ok). Is it possible to view the animation on the Viewer? I translated to SVF2 and loaded the model, but there is nothing referred to the animation...

Is there something more I should include in the translation or some option to use when creating the viewer?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glTF animations are not supported, no matter whether you're loading the glTF file into the viewer directly (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer), or converting it to SVF or SVF2 first, as there hasn't been a demand for this feature.

As a potential workaround, you could try loading the glTF file using the standard three.js loader (which I'm guessing does support animations?) and place it inside a [viewer overlay](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/).